# submit form by button using form.js plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using [this](http://malsup.com/jquery/form/) plugin to submit form with file upload.
Usually my forms are posted (without using this plugint) using:

```
<button id="send">Send</button>
```

and using js like this:

```
$('#send').click(function(){
    ajaxSubmit();
});
```

This plugin is looking for the usual

```
<input type="submit" value="Send">
```

to send the form so that I can keep my buttons instead of the default buttons. My point is to update my click function to trigger form submitting via this plugin.
The plugin is initialized via:

```
$("#myForm").ajaxForm(options);
```

Any help?

My actual workaround is to style input buttons like my standard buttons but I'd prefer to keep all my code the same way (always using buttons to submit forms instead of inputs)

Comment: Can you use `<button id="send" type="submit">Send</button>`? It's one of the examples in the [documentation](http://malsup.com/jquery/form/#ajaxForm)

Comment: Thanks!! Didn't see it! Thank you!

Comment: Glad that it worked. To be honest, it's a bit hidden (I had to check the code to see it)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you check the [documentation](http://malsup.com/jquery/form/#ajaxForm), there are multiple ways of submitting the form with that plugin:

```
<input type="submit" name="submitButton" value="Submit1">
<input type="image" name="submitButton" value="Submit2" src="submit.gif">
<button type="submit" name="submitButton" value="Submit5"><span>submit 5</span></button>
```

You could use the last one. For that, just add `type="submit"` to your button, and it should be enough:

```
<button id="send" type="submit">Send</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing more code, the one thing I can say is that your javascript references an object with an ID of "send" but your `input` has no ID.

Try `<input type="submit" id="send" value="Send"/>`.

Comment: Then I guess I need to see more code then. Care to set up a fiddle?

Comment: he is talkig about usig a button instead of input so that he could style them like other btns on his page.

Comment: @alvaro in his comments has already solved my issue. Thanks anyway